# I need to retrieve a column from already retrieved column from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a table which has a column like this which i retrieved from this query

```
select distinct HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID
from wcadbo.WCA_MDW_D_HLDNGS_DATE 
order by HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID desc;
```

Table:

```
HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID
20210501
20210430
20210429
20210428
```

It contains dates in integer format.

I wrote a query to retrieve another column of these dates in date format and I named column as `AS_OF_DATE` - like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,
    to_date(HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,'YYYYMMDD') AS_OF_DATE
FROM
    WCADBO.WCA_MDW_D_HLDNGS_DATE
ORDER BY
    HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID DESC;
```

Result set:

```
HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID  AS_OF_DATE
----------------------------------
20210501    01-MAY-21
20210430    30-APR-21
20210429    29-APR-21
20210428    28-APR-21
```

Now I need another column as Display_Date in char type which gives LastAvailableDate for latest date in previous column or gives Date in char type for all other dates like this

I wrote this query but not working:

```
SELECT 
    HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,
    AS_OF_DATE,
    Display_date
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,
         to_date(HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,'YYYYMMDD') AS_OF_DATE  
     FROM
         WCADBO.WCA_MDW_D_HLDNGS_DATE
     ORDER BY
         HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID DESC)
WHERE
    Display_Date = (CASE
                        WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '01-MAY-21' 
                            THEN 'Last_Available_date'
                            ELSE TO_CHAR(AS_OF_DATE, 'MON DD YYYY')
                    END);
```

Finally I need three columns, one is already in table but modified a bit. Other two are temporary ones(AS_OF_DATE and Display_Date) that i need to retrieve.

I'm a beginner in SQL and couldn't figure out how to retrieve column from another temporary column..

Kindly help, Thank you.

BTW I was doing it in Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. You will have a better experience of this site if you learn to [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in your posts, and also please when [you ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), tag only the relevant database product you are asking about, not every database product you have used before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this

```
SELECT 
    subQ.HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,
    subQ.AS_OF_DATE,
    (CASE
          WHEN subQ.AS_OF_DATE = date '2021-05-01'
          THEN 'Last_Available_date'
          ELSE TO_CHAR(subQ.AS_OF_DATE, 'MON DD YYYY')
      END) Display_date
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         tbl.HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,
         to_date(tbl.HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID,'YYYYMMDD') AS_OF_DATE  
     FROM
         WCADBO.WCA_MDW_D_HLDNGS_DATE tbl) subQ
ORDER BY
      subQ.HDD_WP_RPTNG_AS_OF_SID DESC
```

Comments

- If you want to add computed columns, that is done in the projection (the `select` list)
- Always compare dates to dates and strings to strings.  So in your `case` statement, compare the `date` `as_of_date` against another date.  In this case I'm using a date literal.  You could also call `to_date` on a string parameter.
- If you want the results of the query ordered by a particular column, you want that `order by` applied at the outermost layer of the query, not in an inline view.
- You basically always want to use aliases when referring to any column in a query.  It's less critical in situations where everything is coming from one table but as soon as you start referencing multiple tables in a query, it becomes annoying to look at a query and not sure where a column is coming from.  Even in a query like this where there is an inline view and an outer query, it makes it easier to read the query if you're explicit about where the columns are coming from.
- Do you **really** need the `distinct`?  I kept it because it was a part of the original query but I get antsy whenever I see a `distinct` particularly from people learning SQL.  Doing a `distinct` is a relatively expensive operation and it is very commonly used to cover up an underlying issue in the query (i.e. that you're getting multiple rows because some other column you aren't showing has multiple values) that ought to be addressed correctly (i.e. by adding an additional predicate to ensure that you're only getting each `hdd_wp_rptg_as_of_sid` once).
- Storing dates as strings in tables (as is done apparently with `hdd_wp_rptg_as_of_sid`) is a really bad practice.  If one person writes one row to the table where the string isn't in the right format, your query will suddenly stop working and start throwing errors, for example.